# Set and resolve PeoplePicker not working

Tags: javascript, people-picker

I've tried the following code to try and set the default values of a peoplepicker field (SP 2013).

```
(window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="https:.../jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>'));
(function defer() {
      if (window.jQuery) {
            jQueryLoaded();
      } else {
           setTimeout(function() { defer() }, 50);
      }
 })();


function jQueryLoaded() {

     var userCurrentSourceLead = "i:0#.w|internal\MyID";
     var pickerTitle = "Requestar";
     var pickerDiv = $('[id$="ClientPeoplePicker"][title="' + pickerTitle + '"]');
     var pickerEditor = pickerDiv.find('[title="' + pickerTitle + '"]');
     var pickerInstance = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[pickerDiv[0].id];
     pickerEditor.val(userCurrentSourceLead);
     pickerInstance.AddUnresolvedUserFromEditor(true);

alert('Routine Ended');

   }
```

The alert "Routine Ended" is displayed, but the field is not set.

Any suggestions on what may be going wrong?

Comment: You can try using sputility.js library to set value of a people picker field. `SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('People_x0020_Picker').SetValue('Work_Email')`

Comment: for more details about usage you can go to http://sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=People%20fields

Comment: Your field is "Requestor" or "Requestar" ? Because you wrote `var pickerTitle = "Requestar"`... Also try with "internal\MyID" instead of "i:0#.w|internal\MyID"

Comment: I used Requestar as an eyecatcher in PF12. Changed the code to try internal\\MyID and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of a way that works for me:

```
// we first make sure that all the required files for PeoplePicker are loaded
SP.SOD.loadMultiple(['sp.core.js', 'sp.runtime.js', 'sp.js', 'autofill.js', 'clientpeoplepicker.js', 'clientforms.js', 'clienttemplates.js'], function() {
  // replace "DISPLAYNAME" with the name that should be shown
  // replace "USERNAME" with "domain\\login" (no need for "i:0#.w|")
  var user = {EntityType:"User", IsResolved:false, DisplayText:DISPLAYNAME, Key:USERNAME, Description:""};
  // Replace "FIELDNAME" with the name of your field name
  // Replace "INTERNALFIELDNAME" with the internal name of your field
  var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict["FIELDNAME_"+WPQ2FormCtx.ListSchema.INTERNALFIELDNAME.Id+"_$ClientPeoplePicker"];
  peoplePicker.AddUnresolvedUser(user, true)
});
```

Comment: Yes, this does work. Great. Just a word on note the UserName field. This  needs to be double backslashed - domain\\login.

My original code must have worked at some stage, but no longer... thinking perhaps some module hadn't been loaded. I've added in the loadMultiple into my original code, and it still doesn't work.

Well I've got two working replacement solutions now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Abdul also works.

You can try using sputility.js library to set value of a people picker field. SPUtility.GetSPFieldByInternalName('People_x0020_Picker').Se‌​tValue('Work_Email') – Abdul Hameed Apr 27 at 6:11

for more details about usage you can go to sputility.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=People%20fields – Abdul Hameed Apr 27 at 6:13